# Measurability in the proof of Minkowski's Bound for calculating the Class Number?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, lebesgue-measure

I recently looked at the proof of [Minkowski's Bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound) given in [Number Rings](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/ant.pdf), and it appeared to implicitly rely on the interesting (and somewhat non-trivial) fact that convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are Lebesgue-measurable. (By way of comparison, this is false for the Borel measure.)

My question: is anyone aware of a proof of Minkowski's Bound that doesn't rely on any non-trivial measure theory? It seems a little funny to me that measure theory would be required to prove a purely number-theoretic statement.

Comment: You must have never heard of Tamagawa measures then. http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Tamagawa_measure

Comment: for the convex subset which is actually used for the proof of the Minkowski bound you certainly don't need any measure theory - the set is compact with a very nice boundary; Riemann integral is all you need

Comment: I suppose there is no need to use the full strength of Minkowski's Theorem (which applies to more or less arbitrary convex sets, and requires facts from measure theory). Both of your comments point to the fact that number theory is only concerned with nice sets, and there aren't any measure theoretic issues that can arise.